# click event on transparent rect with EaselJS

Tags: easeljs

is it possible to make a transparent rect clickable?
I don't want to fill it so it looks like

```
     shape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("#000").rect(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

here is the code how I did it:

```
var shape = new createjs.Shape();    
shape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("#000").rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
var hit = new createjs.Shape();
hit.graphics.beginFill("#000").rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
shape.hitArea = hit;
```

Comment: More details: "EaselJS will calculate mouse hits on a display object based on its visible, non-transparent pixels. ... you can assign any other display object to be the hitArea for your object ... will not be visible." See docs and demo at http://createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/